# Typo in 'Adding Static Code Analysis to Stack Overflow'

Tags: bug, blog, typographical-error

There is a minor typo in the Stack Overflow blog post "[*Adding Static Code Analysis to Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/08/adding-static-code-analysis-to-stack-overflow/?cb=1)".

> Not real code, ’cause by the time I though to take a screenshot we’d already fixed everything.

This should be changed to:

> Not real code, ’cause by the time I **thought** to take a screenshot we’d already fixed everything.

---

And since the post mentions taking a screenshot before things are fixed...

[image: Screenshot of typo]